# res.cls hfill addresses

Tags: cv, resume

I'm trying to have my phone number float to the right margin, but hfill doesn't seem to work within an address in res.cls.

```
\address{email@email.com (555) 555-5555}
```

So I try to change that to:

```
\address{email@email.com \hfill (555) 555-5555}
```

but it doesn't work. hfill has no effect here, any ideas on how to get this to work? I've poked around res.cls but don't see any obvious fixes... well at least for me, I'm a latex noob. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please revise your posting to include a full MWE (minimum working example) rather than just a couple of code snippets. This will help diagnose the issue (or issues, potentially) and simplify others identify a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The class `res.cls` is somewhat old and it is not flexible; I would suggest you to consider using a more modern class to typeset your CV (See [`Writing Applications for a Job / CV`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#applications)). To solve your particular problem, you can use `\parbox`es:

```
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{resume}
\name{ABC}
\address{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\hfill}\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\centering email@email.com}\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\raggedleft (555) 555-5555}}
\opening
\lipsum[4]
\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, the link `http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#applications` seems to be dead.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using `tidyres` package written by me.

It's very flexible, and it allows you to change margin of the CV without any difficulties.

The package is available on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tidyres

**Method:**

With `tidyres` Package, you may use the command below to set the address/phone number.

```
\restitle {<Name>}{<Location>}{<Email>}{<Phone>}{<LinkedinID>}{<link>}
```

The command above could help you generate the essential information (e.g., address, phone number, etc.) easily.

Since the package gives users the flexibility to compile the resume in `article` class or `extarticle` class (if you wish to use 9pt font size), you can also use some basic LaTeX commands to style the title you want.

Comment: +1 for making a package: Instead of "just" adverting for your package, maybe provide a compilable code example that addresses the actual question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @Dr. Manuel Kuehner. I have update my response.

Comment: Great. If you make it even compilable then you are my hero